# Use PhysicsBody with SKShapenode line. Swift, iOS, SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, skshapenode

I need to add simple line using ShapeBody to interact with.
I'am trying code below, by Xcode gives me next response:

> PhysicsBody: Could not create physics body.

```
        let testPath = UIBezierPath()
        testPath.move(to: CGPoint(x:-100, y: 200))
        testPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:100, y: 200))

        let testShape = SKShapeNode()
        testShape.path = testPath.cgPath
        testShape.position = CGPoint(x:0, y:250)
        testShape.zPosition = 5
        testShape.lineWidth = 5
        testShape.strokeColor = .red
        testShape.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFrom: testPath.cgPath)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used edgeChainFrom instead of polygonFrom, and it works!

```
testShape.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeChainFrom: testPath.cgPath)
```

Comment: this means your physicsbody has no volume to it and is not dynamic

Comment: This guy is incredible. Your solution was the only one that worked out of several hours of troubleshooting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A path cannot intersect any of its lines with a SKPhysicsBody,  your line needs to be a thin rectangle

```
    let testPath = UIBezierPath()
    testPath.move(to: CGPoint(x:-100, y: 200))
    testPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:100, y: 200))
    testPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:100, y: 201))
    testPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:-100, y: 201))
    testPath.close()
    let testShape = SKShapeNode()
    testShape.path = testPath.cgPath
    testShape.position = CGPoint(x:0, y:250)
    testShape.zPosition = 5
    testShape.lineWidth = 5
    testShape.strokeColor = .red
    testShape.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFrom: testPath.cgPath)
```